# Canvas into Jquery Step

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I've got a strange problem, I would like to make a signature pad (https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) into a beautiful jquery step.

But my signature pad CANVAS, works only if is after

```
</section>
        </form>
```

If not, I can't write nothing with my mouse.

My project is here : https://jsfiddle.net/jc1agwsk/2/
I don't understant why it doesn't work, and why it works if is not into a step section.

Many thanks

Comment: Please trim your example down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and include it in the question itself (as text, preferably in a snippet).

Comment: Move the creation into the `$(function(){` Also be sure you do not load jQuery twice